# Activity por defecto en Android Studio problema

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Hola como están tengo una consulta:

Lo que sucede es que tengo mi aplicación hecha en Android Studio y tengo tres actividades el Login el menu y el submenu.

Cuando estoy deslogeado y cierro mi aplicación aparece de nuevo en el login para iniciar sesión y eso esta correcto.

El problema esta en que cuando le dejo logueada a la aplicación  y la cierro totalmente, esta en vez de iniciar en el menú principal que quisiera que se abra, siempre se abre en la actividad del sub menú.

Y mi objetivo es lograr que cuando  el usuario logueado así se cierre la aplicación siempre aparezca el menú principal

la pregunta seria hay alguna forma de poner a este menu principal como por defecto cada vez que abro mi aplicación?

Loging esta hecho con Firebase

Esta actividad del sub menu cree primero antes que la del menu principal 
creo que puede ser que este sub menu este por defecto y no se si puedo cambiarla.

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con alguna idea.

Comment: No has pensado en establecer tu `activity` principal cuando se lance el evento (por ejemplo) `void onStop()` asignándole dentro del mimso la pantalla que tiene que cargar.

Comment: Como pudiera Poner este onStop()  me pudieras dar un ejemplo ?

Answer (score 0):

yo diria que pongas el siguiente codigo en la funcion onCreate de tu login.

En Kotlin.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    var mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    if(mAuth!=null){
        intent = Intent(this, EjemploActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

En Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    FirebaseUser mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(mAuth!=null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EjemploActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: ya e intentado con esto lo que pasa es que cuando quiero regresar a esta actividad con medio de botones me manda de nuevo al menu no se si tienes alguna idea de como hacer que se vaya a esta actividad solo cuando cierro la app y la vuelvo a abrir

Comment: Ingresa tu intent :D de ese activity estoy seguro que debes llamar finish() luego de hacer el intent

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tenes que usar es un `AuthStateListener` , esto se va a encargar de escuchar si el mAuth.getCurrentUser() es distinto de null. Si lo es, podemos enviar al usuario a otra pantalla , ya que no nos haria falta volverlo a loguear.

Primero creamos el authListener

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
```

Dentro del `onCreate()` declara este listener, esto lo hacemos con la intencion de que cada vez que el usuario pase por Login.class el listener se dispare y escuche por cambios en el auth, si el usuario esta ya logueado lo dirigimos a la pantalla del submenu

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,SubMenu.class);
                }
            }
        };
```

Luego en el Override del `onStart()` vamos a atachar este listener para que escuche por cambios a nuestro mAuth.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); 
    }
```

Por ultimo `onAuthStateChanged`  se va a lanzar cada vez que

1. Despues de que el Listener fue añadido.
2. Cuando el usuario esta logueado.
3. Cuando el usuario se desloguea.
4. Cuando el usuario actual cambia.

Esto esta marcado en [esta](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#public-methods) documentacion.